# Вживання дієслова "результує"

Tags: вживання-слів, дієслова

Як правильно вживати слово *результує*? Наприклад, який з наступних двох варіантів правильний?

1. Робота результує в оплаті.
2. Робота результує оплатою.

Чи ці два варіанти рівнозначні?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Точно можна сказати:

> Оплата результує з роботи.

Зокрема в праці «Хлопска посiлiсть в Галичинi и новочаснi суспильно-реформаторскi змаганя» В'ячеслава Будзиновського (1895) бачимо:

> З тоі головноі ріжниці, яка заходить між обома соціялістичними партіями, результують дрібнійші, що так скажу тактичні ріжниці.

Загалом конкретні правила щодо цього слова встановити важко, бо хоч воно існує доволі давно, але вживається доволі рідко, через що більшість словників його не фіксують, через що часто не знаходять його й корпуси.

До речі, у Вікісловнику щодо російського слова [«результировать»](//ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) бачимо, що воно може мати зовсім різні значення: 1 «бути наслідком», 2–3 «бути причиною», 4 «підсумовувати» — здається, це стосується й українського слова.

Upd.: З цього [[1]](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac3&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=[word="%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%83(%D1%8E|%D1%94.*|%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%8C|%D0%B2%D0%B0.*)(%D1%81%D1%8C|%D1%81%D1%8F)?"+]), [[2]](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8+OR+%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%83%D1%94+OR+%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B2+OR+%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0+OR+%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8) бачимо, що використовували всі такі варіанти:

- робота результує в оплаті;
- робота результує в оплату;
- робота результує оплатою;
- робота результується в оплаті;
- робота результується в оплату;
- робота результується оплатою.